# Google Firebase cannot verify ownership of Domain.com domain

Tags: firebase, dns, firebase-hosting

I purchased a domain from domain.com and am trying to connect my firebase project to it. I have copy pasted the TXT record as instructed by Firebase, but it still cannot verify my ownersip of the domain. This is a copy of all of the DNS records on domain.com
[image: Image of DNS records]

This is the error given by firebase
[image]

I don't recall where the A address came from. Any ideas on how to confirm the verification?

Comment: When I run `dig anthonyjiang.tech TXT` I don't get a response, so this seems like a problem with your DNS provider moreso than Firebase Hosting.

Comment: Sounds like an answer Michael! :)

Comment: @MichaelBleigh so how can I determine the problem with the DNS provider?

Comment: You should get in touch with domain.com support, answers from 66.96.142.147 (ns1.domain.com) and 65.254.254.171 (ns2.domain.com) have `status: REFUSED` which is kind of strange.